# Restsharp Request gives "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'RestSharp.Method' to 'string?'" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, restsharp

I am trying to call POST API request using restSharp 108.0.1v.

The code is as below;

```
var client = new RestClient("https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.Post);

        request.AddHeader("x-api-key", "MYAPIKEY");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\t\"registrationNumber\":\"AA19AAA\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

        RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

The snippet `Method.Post` of  `var request = new RestRequest(Method.Post);`gives the error that I mentioned.

Please help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: Did you notice that the first parameter for the RestRequest constructor is a string? Remove the "/vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles" from the creation of the RestClient and add it as first parameter for the constructor of RestRequest (or consult their docs on the exact syntax to call to their api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation here](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#create-a-request) the first parameter of the `RestRequest` constructor is the subpath to the resource you want to access. Instead you should do something like the following

```
var client = new RestClient("https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk");
var request = new RestRequest("vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles", Method.Post);

// ... or I believe this should work as well:

var client = new RestClient("https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicle-enquiry/v1");
var request = new RestRequest("vehicles", Method.Post);
```